# Calling saved boolean values for Radio Buttons in Java

Tags: java, radio-button, preferences

So, what I am looking is a way to call the values that I saved to preferences class that can be called up with the clicking of a radio button after the user has defined and saved their inputs.

Class File used for saving and then trying to recall the saved data.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CustomConfig 
{
    public static Properties prop = new Properties();

    public void saveProp(String title, boolean value)
    {
        try
        {
            prop.setProperty(title,String.valueOf(value));
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.radiobutton"),"");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    public String getProp(String title)
    {

        String value = title;
        try
        {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.radiobutton"));
            value = prop.getProperty(title);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
      return value;  
    }
```

I am then using the following code to try to call the radio button(s) that have been defined by the user.

```
private void CustomRadioMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

    con.getProp(CalabrioRadio.getText());
    System.out.println(con.getProp(CalabrioRadio.getText()));
}
```

For good measure here is the text as it was saved initially to the config file...

```
#
#Sun Mar 05 16:09:26 CST 2017
Calabrio=true
CTIOS\ Soft\ Phone=false
Account\ Services=false
Appease=false
Sales\ Ads\ (VMAG)=false
Place\ Order/Oracle=false
Outlook=false
Order\ Status=false
Kronos=false
Collections\ Account\ Services=false
Daily\ Specials=false
HOD\ /\ CCD=false
Intranet\ (AAFES\ Web\ Portal)=false
MyECP.com=false
ShopMyExchange.com=false
```

The issue that I am currently having it, that with the above code, I can't seem to actually call the values back in to change the Selected state of my radio buttons.  When I run the System.out.Println it will however show the correct information.  I am at a loss for what to do at this point as far as getting the buttons to show per the info selected by the user and then saved.  Any help on what to do at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... So I think I finally managed to stumble through to my own answer.  I am going to go ahead and post it just in case anyone is having this issue as well.

So, I am going to re-post everything in the order in which it was originally posted, and will comment out where the changes were made.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CustomConfig 
{
    public static Properties prop = new Properties();

    public void saveProp(String title, boolean value)
    {
        try
        {
            prop.setProperty(title,String.valueOf(value));
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.radiobutton"),"");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    public static boolean getProp(String title) // Modified from Original
    {


        String value = title;
        try
        {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.radiobutton"));
           value = prop.getProperty(title);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
      return Boolean.parseBoolean(value); // Modified from Original
    }

}
```

Next portion will once again be commented on the modified portions.

```
private void CustomRadioMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

    CalabrioRadio.setSelected(con.getProp(CalabrioRadio.getText()));
    // The above line was changed
    System.out.println(con.getProp(CalabrioRadio.getText()));
}
```

With that said, this is working for me now.  So, if anyone else is having this issue, I hope this helps in some way.